# Выбор между языками программирования в колледже

Tags: java, c++

Столкнулся недавно с дилеммой: изучаю java и уже более-менее знаю основы, но поступил в колледж и долгое время программа обучения была не ясна, а теперь, наконец, утвердилось, что учить нас будут c++ (до этого будет ассемблер, но его упустим). Так вот, можете помочь разрешить вопрос: Можно ли учить параллельно java и c++ или нужно просто переходить на c++ и не тратить время?

Comment: К сожалению, нет, не можем.

Comment: учите, знания не бывают лишними

Comment: Учите C++ минимально для учёбы, а Java продолжайте усиленно учить, он не простой. Да и Java программисты много получают

Comment: эммм.... а будто прогер на плюсах меньше??? чушь!!! Я бы советовал опробовать кресты, а только уж потом решать, что делать! Так как с пониманием ++ придёт и понимание, как работает и копьютер, и как устроены более простые языки (по сравнению  с плюсами). Но вы должны осозновать, что ++ - один из самых тяжёлых языков программирования, который будет требовать от вас больших усилий в изучании!

Comment: Больше всего з/п у программистов на перле. Особенно за рубежом. Учите перл. Учите углублённо!

Comment: можно учить и яву и си и квантовую механику, если с ума начнешь сходить отбрось сначала механику, если наоборот, добавь к списку ядерную физику.

Comment: Java - Си-подобный язык. Учите два параллельно, проблем не будет. Ведь в программировании главное не язык на котором пишете, а то как вы это делаете. Так что больше уделяйте внимания основам, а язык приложится, главное писать код.

Comment: И плюс к этому заодно научитесь быстро переключаться с языка на язык. Конечно, часто вы устраиваетесь на работу, где пользуетесь одним языком. Но кругозор еще никому сильно не мешал. И бывают работы (особенно для тимлидов, архитекторов и т.п.) где вы в день одновременно что то делаете на 5 языках ...